# Nested for loop to go through every combination in text file

Tags: python

Below is the code I have:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for i in f:

        for j in f:

            pw_n= i+j
            print(pw_n)
```

Sample data from test.txt is:

```
USA
Canada
Mexico
China
Russia
```

Output Currently:

```
USA
CANADA

USA
MEXICO

USA
China

USA
Russia
```

The above is great but I would like it to go through all iterations. So, after it finishes USA, I would like it to go to Canada then Mexico, etc... Ex.:

```
Canada
USA

Canada
Canada

Canada
Mexico
..........
```

Any help regarding this would be great. I've tried to increment 'i' by 1 but that wasn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: First read file lines into a list then iterate over the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stay as close as possible to your current code, you should use `file.readlines()`:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in lines:
        for j in lines:
            pw_n = i + j
            print(pw_n)
```

As an addition, I would recommend changing `lines = f.readlines()` to:

```
lines = [x.rstrip('\n') + '\n' for x in f.readlines()]
```

That list comprehension will force all words to end with a `'\n'` (in your file `Russia` doesn't have any `'\n'` at the end and so it is shown differently on the output, this fixes that).

If you are looking for a better code you should use [`itertools.permutations(iterable, r=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), where `r` is the number of items per combinations (in this case we need 2)

```
from itertools import permutations
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for x, y in permutations(f.readlines(), 2):
        print(x + y)
```

You may also improve this code by adding:

```
for x, y in permutations((x.rstrip('\n') + '\n' for x in f.readlines()), 2):
```

Here a list comprehension isn't needed, instead, we can use a generator expression, which is more memory friendly.

Since you are iterating over each permutation inside a `for` loop, in no moment you need to store it as a list, that means you don't need to store on memory all the permutations at the same time, instead, they are calculated as you use them. The same applies to the generator expression, you don't store it in opposition with the list comprehension from the first code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

```
>>> list(permutations(['USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico'], 2)) 
[
    ('USA', 'Canada'), 
    ('USA', 'Mexico'), 
    ('Canada', 'USA'), 
    ('Canada', 'Mexico'), 
    ('Mexico', 'USA'), 
    ('Mexico', 'Canada')
]
```

Comment: Hi @Vince if the permutations() works for the above list, why would it not work for the 2000 lines you have?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for i, val in enumerate(lines):
    for j in range(i+1, len(lines)):
        print("%s%s" %(val, lines[j]))
    print("")
```